# Event handler on JavaScript prompt object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

**How do you use events with a JavaScript prompt object?**

A user is asked to provide user input into a JavaScript prompt window. The user input may only contain numerical values. Is there any possiblity to attach an event handler to the textfield of the prompt object (event type: onkeyup)?

Answer (score 1):

There are no events provided on the `prompt`. The best course of action is not to use it.

Instead, try a modal window containing HTML which you will have full control over.